# Trying to wait until multiple images upload to cloudinary

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

I am stuck trying to upload multiple images to Cloudinary and send back the cloudinary urls in an array back in the response. I have been trying to figure out a way to wait for the loop to finish before sending back photoAlbum array, but with no luck. Code looks somethign like this:

server.js

```
app.post('/uploadimages', async (req, res) => {
    const { imgFiles, username } = req.body;

    const photoAlbum = await cloudinaryUpload(imgFiles, username)
    
    res.send(photoAlbum)
})
```

cloudinary.js

```
require("dotenv").config()
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2


module.exports.cloudinaryUpload = async (imgFiles, username) => {
    const photoAlbum = []

    await imgFiles.forEach((img) => {
        const imageid = uuidv4();

        cloudinary.uploader.upload(
            img,
            {
                folder: username,
                resource_type: "image",
                public_id: imageid,
            }).then((result) => {
                console.log("*** Success: Cloudinary Upload: ", result.url);
                photoAlbum.push({ imageid: imageid, url: result.url });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("*** Error: Cloudinary Upload");
            })
    })

    console.log("Cloudinary upload done: ", photoAlbum);

    return photoAlbum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` will always return `void` - undefined in JS - regardless of the callback. What you'd like to do is return an array of promises, and then wait for them all to finish.
For that to happen, you should use a combination of `map` and `Promise.all`.

```
const promises = imgFiles.map(() => {
  const imageid = uuidv4();

   return cloudinary.uploader.upload(
            img,
            {
                folder: username,
                resource_type: "image",
                public_id: imageid,
            }).then((result) => {
                console.log("*** Success: Cloudinary Upload: ", result.url);
                photoAlbum.push({ imageid: imageid, url: result.url });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("*** Error: Cloudinary Upload");
            });
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

The `map` function creates a new array of promises, thanks to the `return cloudinary.uploader.upload`, that the `Promise.all` takes to, with the combination of `await`, wait for all the images to upload.